# How can i fix this PHP error - Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable?

Tags: php

i'm getting an error on this line , not sure how i would go about correcting it , any help ?

I have zero to no php abilities and just want to fix and error on some work i had done.  Also will the fix be backwards compatible from PHP7 to PHP5 ?

```
for($k=0;$k<count($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']);$k++){
```

Comment: it means that `$_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']` isn't an array / multidimensional variable and it can't iterate on it. This would encapsulate it: `if ( 
!empty($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']) ) { for($k=0;$k<count($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']);$k++){ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 7.2, if you call count() on a variable that is not "countable", PHP shows a warning about it. A common fix was to check if the given variable is "countable" before calling count() on it.

A "countable" variable is either an array, or an object of a class that implements \Countable interface. Because there can be a lot of boilerplate code, PHP 7.3 now has a new is_countable() function that returns true if the passed variable is... well... countable.

https://php.watch/versions/7.3#new-is_countable-function

I would do something like this:

```
if(isset($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']) && is_countable($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']) {
    for($k=0;$k<count($_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']);$k++){
        ...
    }
}
```

if you are below 7.3 put this polyfill into your code:

```
if (!function_exists('is_countable')) {
    function is_countable($var) { 
        return is_array($var) 
            || $var instanceof Countable 
            || $var instanceof ResourceBundle 
            || $var instanceof SimpleXmlElement; 
    }
}
```

Comment: can i place the polyfill anywhere in the php file ?

Comment: yes anywhere somewhere before it is being used. The beginning of the file would be good or in a general include file if you use something like that.

Comment: It needs to be in the code before the function is is_countable is called

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `$_matchup['franchise'][$m]['player']` is actually a variable which can be counted. As the error message indicated.

Such as an Array

This line of code should be compatible with both PHP5 and PHP7